# User Snippets for Svelte in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, vscode-snippets

I struggle to create a simple snippet for .svelte files or Svelte project.
Here's the procedure i've tried:

1. Ctrl + Maj + P to open "Preference: Configure user Snippets"
2. New Global Snippets File ... typed svelte to create the svelte.json file
3. Inside of it the below code

```html
{
  "test": {
    "scope": "Svelte",
    "prefix": "xx",
    "body": ["This is a simple test"],
    "description": "Code snippet for testing"
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The scope id for Svelte is probably `svelte` lowercase.  You do not need to remove the `scope` selector but itis redundant if it is already inside the svelte.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope id for Svelte is probably `svelte` lowercase. If you click on the `Svelte` language id button in the lower right when you have a `.svelte` file open, you can look through those language ids for `svelte` - the correct version to use is that in the parentheses like

`Svelte (svelte)`  use the version in parentheses - `svelte` lowercased

```
{
  "test": {
    "scope": "svelte",
    "prefix": "xx",
    "body": ["This is a simple test"],
    "description": "Code snippet for testing"
  }
}
```

Works fine in a `.svelte` file.

You do not need to remove the scope selector but it is redundant if it is already inside the `svelte.json` file which limits all snippets within it to that filetype.

Comment: Thank you for the language id type (s underscore) but it doesn't work either. I've tried both using a Global Snippets File using the scope property as well as a svelte.json file without the scope prop :/

Comment: I tested it and it works in a `.svelte` file.  What is your file extension and what does the language ID button in the lower right say?

Comment: File extension is `.svelte`, Language Mode is automatically set to `Svelte` and the id is `svelte`

Comment: My bad! Actually, for the snippet to work, the keystrokes has to happen outside of the <script> and <style> tag. So, VSCode knows how to make a difference between styles, scripts and svelte code inside the same .svelte file. Thank you for you help mate